# Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd' when using stability function in ClustOfVar

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I tried to apply stability function in ClustOfVar package and got an error message as below:

```
Error in La.svd(x, nu, nv) : error code 1 from Lapack routine 'dgesdd'.
```

I intended to do the variable clustering on a data set including both quantitative and qualitative variables. The R codes I uses are shown as below. At first I use the data directly (i.e., without standardization of the quantitative variables) and got the error message when running the `stability` function). Then I scale the quantitative variables and rerun the codes and got the same error message. Would someone give a suggestion how to fix the problem? Also, I do not think it need no step to standardize the quantitative variables because the `hclustvar` function should contain the standardization, right?

```
X.quanti<-Data4Cluster[, c(9:28)]
X.quanti2<-scale(X.quanti, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)
X.quali<-Data4Cluster[, c(1:4,8)]

tree<-hclustvar(X.quanti,X.quali)
plot(tree)
stab<-stability(tree, B=40)

tree2<-hclustvar(X.quanti2,X.quali)
plot(tree2)
stab<-stability(tree2, B=40)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am having exactly the same problem. The only thing that fixed it for me was changing the value of B (reducing it to 20) but I don't think it is right so I hope someone can give us a solution. My worry from searching the web is that there is a bug in the Lapack package which seems unfixable (this error is a common occurrence with various functions).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error using the `MASS::lda` function. The error went away when I removed collinear variables from the model.